# SQL query about sum of values between 2 dates

Tags: sql, database, oracle-apex

I have an Apex Oracle app to do. This is the app description: A touristic destination is defined by its name and description. Each touristic destination has a number of bookings, defined by start date, end date, description, price as in the following example: Touristic destination: Hotel Sunrise, Hawaii `Start date: 18-Aug-2014` `End date: 01-Sep-2014` `Description: One room with breakfast` `included Price: 2000`

For the app I made 2 tables:
`Destinations(ID: number, Name:varchar2, Description: varchar2)` and `Bookings(BID: number, ID: number, start_date: date, end_date: date, description: varchar2, price:number)`

One requirement consists of a report that shows all the bookings completely between a given start and end date and their total price. I have the query but it does not show the total price, only the information about the bookings between those dates.
This is the query:

```
SELECT b.bid, b.start_date, b.end_date, SUM(b.price) as total_price
FROM Bookings b
WHERE b.START_DATE>=:START_DATE AND b.END_DATE<=:END_DATE
GROUP BY b.bid, b.start_date, b.end_date;
```

Can someone spot the mistake?

Comment: could you try with sum(nvl(b.price,0) wonder null values present in your table?

Comment: If `bid` is a primary key of the table then you are going into wrong direction. Show some sample data and expectes outcome.

Answer (score 1):

It's just because you are using start_date and end_date inside your grouping clause. This usage causes data be grouped over start_date and end_date too!
You should do something like this:

```
WITH Result AS(
  SELECT b.bid, SUM(b.price) as total_price
  FROM Bookings b
  WHERE b.START_DATE>=:START_DATE AND b.END_DATE<=:END_DATE
  GROUP BY b.bid
)

SELECT *,:start_date as start, :end_date as end
FROM Result
```

Comment: I tried that code and it does have a weird error on an empty line.It says "line 8: FROM keyword not found where expected", where line 8 is the line after the end paranthesis.

Comment: It may because some reserved words I used in my query, Just rename the words 'start', 'end', and 'Result' with your own words and the error will disappear